# php: how to identify empty row in textarea

Tags: php, string, textarea, row

I have a textarea and I'm trying to check if row is not empty. Seems these doesn't work:

```
if(!empty($stringArray[$i])) {

if(isset($stringArray[$i])) {

if($stringArray[$i] != '') {

if($stringArray[$i] != ' ') {
```

$stringArray is array with elements(strings) that were exploded by "\n".
Any ideas how to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way->

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$stringArray[$i]);

if(strlen($string) > 0){

echo 'not empty';

}
```

Remove whitespaces and check the length of the string (`strlen`)